# jQuery break .each() with timeout

Tags: jquery, google-maps, settimeout, each, break

I'm working with google Maps and want to show multiple markers.
If you enter the name of a city, the map jumps to the location and you get a list with all companys in the region. By pressing a button, every company shall be shown on the map.
The markers shall drop with a small delay so I made a function like this:

```
$('#show_markers').click(function()
{
  $('.div_with_information').each(function(index)
  {
    var location = $(this);//includes multiple infomations like lat, lng, name, info...
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      set_marker(location);//function to create google marker with infobox ect.
    },100*index);
  });
});
```

This works perfectly well. I need the delay for a nice drop animation and to check the coordinates of the marker. 
But sometimes there are many markers to drop an the script need a lot of time.

What I am looking for is a function to stop the "marker rain" completely.

```
$('#stop_button').click(stop_drop);
```

I tried many things, but nothing worked as I wish.
I hope you got some good Ideas.

Comment: Do you wish to stop it definitely or just for a while? If definitely, setTimeout returns an integer that can be used to cancel the callback with the function clearTimeout. So store those integers somewhere and just call clearTimeout when you want the rain to stop.

Comment: for the moment a total stop is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var is_running = false;
var timeout;

$('#show_markers').click(function()
{
  if (is_running)
    return;

  is_running = true;

  var index = 0;
  var divs = $('.div_with_information');
  var num = divs.length;

  timeout = setTimeout(on_set_marker_event, 100);

  function on_set_marker_event()
  {
    var location = divs.eq(index);
    set_marker(location);

    index++;

    if (is_running && index < num)
       timeout = setTimeout(on_set_marker_event, 100);
  });
});

$('#stop_button').click(function()
{      
  is_running = false;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I knew I had to call a clearTimeout() but i had no clue how to combine it with .each()